# Using R variable to determine date in blogdown talk

Tags: r, yaml, blogdown

this may be trivial or simply impossible, but I would like to allow the date of a `blogdown` "talk" to be determined by a R expression. The way I thought about it something like that

```
# Some R code to define a variable 't0', which is a string to contain the start date in 
# a format that `blogdown` will like for the yaml field 'date'
```

```
---
title: My title here
date: '`r t0`'
### Other yaml variables
---
```

I assumed that that would work, but instead, I get an error

```
Quitting from lines X-XX () 
Error in eval(parse_only(code), envir = envir) : object 't0' not found
```

Looks like the R code is not "ported" onto the yaml? (I have managed in `blogdown` to use the `!expr SOME_R_INLINE_EXPRESSION` to add a variable to the yaml, but in this case it just doesn't seem to work...).

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks
Gianluca